# Why does the data on website not match what is returned from the api

Tags: data-request, api, openfda

I am trying to get data similar to what is shown on https://www.fda.gov/Safety/Recalls/default.htm using the api, but I am seeing a lot of discrepancies.

For example when I use the following api call: https://api.fda.gov/food/enforcement.json?search=recalling_firm:%22safeway%22&limit=100 then I see a total of 10 results returned. If I do the same search on the recall website using "Safeway" as the keyword, I only see 5 results returned. What am I missing to get these data sets to match up?

I also see in the food api endpoint searchable fields that the openfda object is listed as searchable, but it always returns empty when when using the food api. Is there another way to get the brand name for food items using this api?

Thank you for your help!!!

Comment: more fun: their archive won't resolve if you search for 'Safeway' https://www.fda.gov/Safety/Recalls/ArchiveRecalls/default.htm and this archive has another number of results: https://www.archive-it.org/collections/7993?q=Safeway&show=ArchivedPages&hitsPerDupe=0&go=Search+the+Archive

Answer (score 0):

Since you are querying the Food *Enforcement* endpoint in openFDA, you would have to look at the Enforcement Reports page at the FDA available at https://www.accessdata.fda.gov/scripts/ires/index.cfm in order for the data to match up. Enforcement Reports at the FDA is where openFDA Enforcement endpoints get their data from.

Unfortunately, none of the Food Enforcement query results will have an `openfda` section populated. There is no harmonization information for foods available to us. Thus the `recalling_firm` field is your best bet.